# jQuery breaks all other scripts despite "(function($) { })(jQuery);" wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a photography portfolio page and want to use different jQuery slideshows for each photo group.  I realize having lots of different scripts can cause conflicts, but I've made sure that each script is wrapped with `(function($) { })(jQuery);` to avoid conflicts with the $.

All the scripts played nice together until I added one particular script (jquery.RotateImageMenu.js).  It is definitely this script that breaks everything because when I comment it out, everything works fine.  Even the other scripts required for that plugin are fine.  As soon as I uncomment that script tag, *all* the jQuery on the page breaks.  There are no console errors.

Because there are so many files, I threw it all up on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/ydfsc4tCnlehapmXjpkz) so the all code is in one place.

I'm aware that none of the images work on Plunker because it was enough of a pain to copy and paste all the script files, let alone go through over 100 image tags and put in direct links.

I am also aware that there may be an easier way to load all these scripts, but at the moment the goal is to get them all to work before figuring out ways to condense.  Well, unless combining would eliminate the problem.  To be honest, I have no idea if that would work or not or if there's an easier way to go about this.  Any suggestions for an easier approach are welcome, even if they aren't necessarily a solution for how I have things set up at the moment.

Comment: Can you put your code here?

Comment: Wrapping jQuery like so `(function($) { })(jQuery);` is needed only when there are multiple libraries e.g. jQuery and extJS being used together, each of which by default try to use the same `$` alias. In your case since you are only using jQuery there does not seem to any need of that wrapping.

Comment: The code is all here: 
http://plnkr.co/ydfsc4tCnlehapmXjpkz

There are 8 javascript files and 3 css files.  Not really enough space to put it all here.

Comment: A quick look at jquery.RotateImageMenu.js gives 'd is already defined'. Might have something to do with the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  I don't see 'd' anywhere in that file.  'e' and 'delta,' but no 'd.'